# Why is there no `\endgroup`?

Tags: macros, def

I see this code in the book's source "The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX":

```latex
\newcommand{\CTANref}{\begingroup \urlstyle{tt}\Url}     %
\def\CTAN|#1|{\href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/#1}{\CTANref|CTAN://#1|}}
```

1. Why is there no `\endgroup` in CTANref?
2. Is `\def\CTAN|#1|` same as `\def\CTAN[#1]`?
3. Why use `\def` and `\newcommand` both? Couldn't `\newcommand` at both places have worked?
4. How can I implement the above using just one macro?

Comment: you can not define a command with `|` delimited arguments using `\newcommand`

Comment: I wouldn't take this code as a model for something, there is no real reason visible why a delimited argument is used here.

Comment: There are 2 delimited arguments here. After some experimentation, I found out how `\def` delimited arguments work. If I use `\def\CTAN|#1|`, I have to use `\CTAN|someting|` to expand it, if I use `\def\CTAN<#1<`, I have to use `\CTAN<something<`.

But I still don't get it how `\CTANref|CTAN://#1|` works. Its like `CTAN://#1` is an argument to `\CTANref`, and yet that it has not been defined to take in any arguments. Could you throw some light on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `\Url` will provide the missing `\endgroup`.

One sees in `url.sty` the definition of `\url`:

```latex
\def\DeclareUrlCommand#1#2{\def#1{\leavevmode\begingroup #2\Url}}

% Sample (and default) configuration:
%
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{}
```

which means it does

```
\leavevmode\begingroup\Url
```

The code you quote is modeled on this.  The actual `\endgroup` comes from `\Url@z` in particular.  Check `url.sty` source code.

Comment: I looked into `url.sty`, but I did not understand much, I have not mastered TeX enough. For now however, this is sufficient for me to know `\endgroup` happened becasue `\Url` provided it internally, and `\leavevmode` and `\Url@z` are my pointers for the future.